# Codeigniter : word_limiter, how to include the images?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am displaying a blog preview content on my main page, then there's a "read more" button to goto a single page to read the whole blog content,it's working great but when my users puts on images into their blog the preview becomes to long, is there a way to exclude the images from my preview using codeigniter?

My code is below.

```
<?php echo word_limiter($doc['body'] , 60);?>
```

Now my body content is below i am saving it via WYSIWYG

```
<h1>Sample title</h1><p><br></p><p><img style="width: 603px;" src="http://localhost/documentation/assets/uploads/doctors.png"></p><p><br></p><p><img style="width: 626px;" src="http://localhost/documentation/assets/uploads/hand-drawn-child-with-a-face-mask_23-2147543791.jpg"><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

Any suggestions is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: are you posting images through WYSIWYG editor..??

Comment: Yes i am using summernote.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip_tags()` could have been an efficient option but it would remove all tags and I guess you want to keep other tags. You can use regular expression to remove images from the contents. Try the following.

```
$doc['body'] = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "[Image Removed]", $doc['body']);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this one instead of showing all details in preview you can show title with some details regarding that blog after that read more having linked slug for blog detail

```
$content = '<h1>Sample title</h1><p><br></p><p><img style="width: 603px;" src="http://localhost/documentation/assets/uploads/doctors.png"></p><p><br></p><p><img style="width: 626px;" src="http://localhost/documentation/assets/uploads/hand-drawn-child-with-a-face-mask_23-2147543791.jpg"><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>';

    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i","", $content); 
    echo $content;
```